# PHP: How to access resource returned by imagescale function

Tags: php

After resizing an image with the imagescale function, how can I get the file path of the resized image?

The docs indicate that the return value is:
"Return the scaled image resource on success or FALSE on failure."
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagescale.php

```
$source= imagecreatefrompng($file['file']['tmp_name']);             
$file =  imagescale($source, 150, 150, IMG_BICUBIC);
```

$file seems to only contain "resource(8, gd). How do I get the file path of the new the scaled image?

Comment: It only exists in memory, use other methods like `imagepng()` to actually get the image data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you called `$file` is actually not a file, but a *resource*, i.e., a piece of information containing your image in memory. To save it to a file, append the following line after your code:

```
imagepng($file, "/path/to/file.png");
```

`imagepng()` returns a bool, so you might check if it succeeded.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php.